# How to generate ABBAABBA... sequence with PHP and CSS nth-child

Tags: php, css

I have a two column layout with this disposition of elements:

> A  B
>   B  A
>   A  B
>   B  A
>   …

`A` and `B` elements have content from different origins and also different styles. So, I'm trying to find an expression to generate this `A B B A A B B A …` sequence both in PHP and CSS nth-child.

This is what I'm doing to generate the layout:

```
/* $post_ids is an Array of ID's */

$count = count( $post_ids );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    $classes = ['teaser', 'lg-6', 'md-6', 'sm-12'];
    if ( ( 2 * $i ) % 2 == 0 ) { // This is wrong. Always true!
        $classes[] = 'a-element';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'b-element';
    }
    insert_post( $post_ids[ $i ], $classes ); // This is a custom function
}
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.teaser:nth-child(2n) { // Also wrong
    /* Styles for A items */
}
```

I know once I got the correct PHP sequence I could replace my CSS with:

```
.a-element {…}
.b-element {…}
```

But I'd like to know if this could be also done with `nth-child`...

I guess it can't be that hard, but I'm kinda stuck with this... Any hint or help will be much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** After @axiac's answer and some [research](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/qt/how-to-use-nth-child-expressions.htm), I've learned that `nth-child` only allows:

- a number - any positive integer (1,2,3,20, etc.)
- a keyword - even or odd
- an expression - in the form of an+b (a, b being integers)

So, I guess what I want can't be done with CSS's `nth-child`. Thank you guys!

Comment: $i%2==0 will be fine.

Comment: you have used 2 * $i which will always give you an even number , as Ravi Hirani said remove the 2 from the start..

Comment: My code is obviously wrong because, as you said, `2 * $i` is always even. But `$i % 2 == 0` isn't correct either. Notice that in may layout there are both even and odd elements of every type (`A` and `B`)

Comment: `( 2 * $i ) % 2` is always `0`!

Comment: Thank you for your interest @axiac. In previous comments we've already noticed it.

Comment: If the CSS expressions are not correct you better edit the question and remove them. Right now the question is confusing. The "image" displays the sequence "A B B A A B B A A B B ..." but the CSS describes the sequence "A B A B A B ...". Which one do you need?

Comment: I need `A B B A A B B A…`. I'll edit my question again to clarify. Thank you for your suggestion @axiac

Comment: So basically you are repeating ABBA sequence. The condition can look like this `$i % 4 == 1 || $i % 4 == 2`

Comment: Thank you @cdm. This works too.

Comment: and you can also use it in css: `.teaser:nth-child(4n+1), .teaser:nth-child(4n+2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code you need is:

```
if ((int)(($i + 1) / 2) % 2 == 0 ) {
    $classes[] = 'a-element';
} else {
    $classes[] = 'b-element';
}
```

**Update**

At OP's request, this is how I produced the code above. The desired outcome is:

```
A B B A A B B A ..
```

- after the initial `A` each symbol repeats twice. We use a `for (;;)` loop to iterate from `0` to some `$n` greater than zero;
- the alternation is provided by the modulo operation (`% 2`);
- grouping the values can be done by finding a common property for consecutive numbers. The integer result of division by the desired group size is such a property. If you need to output 5 `A`s followed by 5 `B`s then you just notice that any positive integer number can be written as `5 * k + r` where `r` is one of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` (this is how the [division of integer numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) works). There are exactly `5` consecutive integer numbers that divided by `5` produce the same integer result (and different remainders);
- given that the PHP division always produce real numbers, the conversion of the result to int (by [type casting the result to `(int)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)) is needed;
- the `+ 1` offset is needed to "push" one `A` before the first 2 `B`s. `0` and `1` produce the same result (`0`) when divided by `2` (they make the first group), `2` and `3` produce `1` and make the second group and so on.

#### Generalization

If you need to produce `N` different types of blocks (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` a.s.o.), each of them appear `M` consecutive times (`A A A B B B C C C D D D ...`, `M` is `3` here) then the formula is:

```
(int)(($i + $k) / M) % N
```

The value produced by this formula is one of `0`, `1` ... `N - 1` and it tells what symbol to use (`A`, `B` a.s.o.). Without `+ $k` this formula generates `M` instances of `A` followed by `M` instances of `B`, `M` instances of `C` and so on until the last symbol. It prints `M * N` symbols in total then it starts over with `A`.

The value of `$k` is one of `0 .. M * N - 1` and it allows the sequence to start from any point inside the sequence. It represents the number of symbols to skip from the start of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you @axiac. It works! Could you please explain how you found the expression?

Comment: Awesome explanation @axiac. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the problem is with:

```
(2 * $i) % 2 == 0
```

this will return true for all iterations (2 * $i) is always even

try:

```
$i % 2 == 0
```

instead

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately `$i % 2 == 0` isn't correct. This expression gives me a sequence equivalent to _even_, _odd_, _even_, _odd_... But notice that in may layout there are both even and odd elements of every type. My first `B` element is odd, but the 2nd is even. So `$i % 2 == 0` won't work (I've tried)

Comment: so you want it to be: A then 2 B's then 2 A's etc?

Comment: Yes, it could be expressed this way too :)